# Android swipe - should I use Gesture listener or MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE?

Tags: android

Which of the two is better to use to do left/right swipe of a list item in a Recycler view? 
Currently my code sits in a MotionEvent.Action_move, and I'm not able to figure out a lot of things.

1. The motion is not smooth at all. Very choppy. And the list item always starts moving after a slight delay.
2. Figuring out which is my gesture - right or left?

I was going through the code of AndroidSwipeListView and they don't seem to be using Gesture listeners. Hence, I asked.

Code in Action_move that does the movement

```
               float posX = v.getX();
                float velocityX = Math.abs(velocityTracker.getXVelocity());

                float x = posX - event.getRawX();
                if (x < 0) {
                    posX += event.getRawX() / 100 + velocityX / 10;

                }
                else {
                    posX -= event.getRawX() / 100 + velocityX / 10;

                }
                v.animate().translationX(posX)
                        .alpha(0.8f);
```

Second edit with some more code:

```
public ViewHolder(final View itemView, int ViewType) {                 // Creating ViewHolder Constructor with View and viewType As a parameter
            super(itemView);

            //itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            // Here we set the appropriate view in accordance with the the view type as passed when the holder object is created
            //itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnTouchListener(this);

            Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.avg_price);         // Creating Text View object from header.xml for name
            email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);       // Creating Text View object from header.xml for email
            Holderid = 0;                                                // Setting holder id = 0 as the object being populated are of type header view



             swipeDetector = new GestureDetector(itemView.getContext(),
                    new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                        float x;
                        float y;

                        @Override
                        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                            x = 0;
                            y = 0;
                            Log.d("onDown", "here");
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                                                float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                            x -= distanceX;
                            y -= distanceY;
                            Log.d("scrolling", "here");
                            Log.d("view", itemView.toString());

                            //View view = itemView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                            if (Math.abs(x) > Math.abs(y)) {
                                //Horizontal
                                if (x > 0) {

                                    //posX -= distanceX;
                                    Log.d("no", String.valueOf(distanceX));

                                    //itemView.animate().translationX(distanceX)
                                    //      .alpha(0.8f);
                                    //right
                                } else {
                                    //left
                                }
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });


    }


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             VelocityTracker velocityTracker = null;
            int index = event.getActionIndex();
            int action = event.getActionMasked();
            int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);
            float downX = 0;
            float posX = v.getX();
            return swipeDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Please post your code. I have an idea why you could have a choppy result with ACTION_MOVE but seeing the code would be helpful.

Comment: @DavidM Posted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GestureDetector` can be easy to use to determine a swipe gesture from `MotionEvent`s.

```
//Make a GestureDetector
swipeDetector = new GestureDetector(GLView.getContext(),
                new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                    float x;
                    float y;
                    @Override
                    public boolean onDown (MotionEvent e){
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0;
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                            float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                        x -= distanceX;
                        y -= distanceY;
                        if(Math.abs(x) > Math.abs(y)){
                            //Horizontal
                            if(x > 0){
                              //right
                            }else{
                              //left
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });



//Feed your MotionEvent to swipeDetector from your View
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){ 
    return swipeDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Below is a sample `Adapter` with `GestureDetector` you may want to begin with.

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private int count = 50;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getItem(int position) {
        return Integer.valueOf(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder h;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(parent.getContext(), R.layout.list_item, null);
            h = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(h);
        } else {
            h = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        h.tv.setText("" + (position + 1));
        h.tv.setTranslationX(0);
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder implements View.OnTouchListener {
        View row;
        TextView tv;
        GestureDetector swipeDetector;

        ViewHolder(View convertView) {
            row = convertView;
            tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            row.setOnTouchListener(this);
            swipeDetector = new GestureDetector(row.getContext(), new GestureDetector
                    .SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                float x;
                float y;

                @Override
                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                    x = 0;
                    y = 0;
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float
                        distanceY) {
                    x -= distanceX;
                    y -= distanceY;
                    if (Math.abs(x) > Math.abs(y)) {
                        //Horizontal
                        if (x > 0) {
                            tv.setTranslationX(x);
                        } else {
                            //left
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL && event.getAction() !=
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                return swipeDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
            tv.setTranslationX(0);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Though I've not implemented it yet, will it solve the choppiness issue and make the movement smoother?

Comment: Generally GestureDetector can give you smoother events than raw MotionEvents by cutting off the noise.

Comment: Thanks! I will implement it right away, and get back to you if the choppiness remains.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that GestureListener has no clue which view item I'm tapping on. It doesn't translate well on a listview.

Comment: @IamH1kc if you use the GestureListener on your whole ListView, it would be hard to know which item you're tapping on. But if you use the GestureListener on every single item view, it will be much easier.

Comment: I've put the gesture listener inside my viewholder. Have done some more edit to my question, to show the code I'm currently using.

Comment: @IamH1kc where do you think things go wrong? Can you comment it out in your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82899/discussion-between-songchenwen-and-iamh1kc).